# How to define localhost on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a very simple web app and deployed to google Kubernetes(LoadBalancer) and it is working fine. I can access my `index.html` like this `my_external_IP:8080/myweb/html/index.html`.

The `index.html` is a frameset which loads other htmls. But the html URLs are hardcoded like http://localhost/html/my_frame1.html in my code. But Google Kubernetes is complaining about localhost refusing to connect. I can not define localhost to my external IP before I create my war. The external IP is known to me long after.

Deployment info is in the following:
[LoadBalancer service not reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56997861/loadbalancer-service-not-reachable)

Comment: This is not with respect to kubernetes. For any web app, you can refer the other files in a HTML with relative path.

Answer (score 1):

As @malathi mentioned, this is not related to Google Kubernetes at all.

Instead of using hardcoded values I recommend using [Relative Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028813/2989261). Basically, all your paths in your initial index.html would need to direct to `html/...`.